# multiple input entry search in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Any idea on how to search multiple text input either as strings with comma separation or nextline (inline search)

example: search  (SPEED1, SPEED2, SPEED3). and get results for all the SPEEDs

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hmert/inline-search provides this functionality for inline search.

Comment: I only want to search multiple inputs from different models. I'm using haystacks search for this. I wasn't using views... is it possible to perform a string search of several entries separated by comma or space. for instance in a search_box I input : book1, book2,... and search for these items in two or more models.

Comment: I'm using haystack and whoosh for my search. But I wanted to be able to search multiple input elements all at a time. Example as done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802628/search-for-multiple-words-elasticsearch-haystack